# how to use whole page body as droppable using dropzone js

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, dropzone.js

I am using Dropzone.js in my ruby on rails project and I am in requirement to do html body as droppable so I can drop files anywhere on the page , I have seen this on JIRA while creating new stories , the did exactly I want . following is my code

```
in js file I did the following 
------------------------------------------------

Dropzone.options.documentDropzone = {
autoProcessQueue: false,
init: function() {
myDropzone = this;

var submitButton = document.querySelector("#buttondropzone")

submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
   myDropzone.hiddenFileInput.click();
});

this.on("addedfile", function(file) { 
  $("#smallModal").modal('show');
});

this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData){
    if ($("#docName").val() == ""){
      this.removeAllFiles(true);
    }else {
     //formData.append('name', $("#docName").val());
    }

});
this.on("success",function(file,data){
  this.removeAllFiles(true);
});

}


my form looks like the following 
---------------------------------------
 = simple_form_for @object , url: someurl , :html => {id: 'document-dropzone', class: 'dropzone', multipart: true} do |f| 
    = f.input :document ,:as => :file  , :label => false , :input_html => {class: "hide"}
```

I have checked the following link [Make the whole body a dropzone](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Make-the-whole-body-a-dropzone) , but they directly configured dropzone to document.body but in my case I configured dropzone for form and went with options in js file .

Can anyone help how to make my entire page as droppable

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

This will help you: https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Make-the-whole-body-a-dropzone

I used this and it worked really well. It's a tutotial to use a dropzone in a full page, but you think a little, you can transform his button or the button's background in a drop zone easily.

```
<!doctype html>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="dropzone.css" />
<script src="dropzone.js"></script>


<!--
Don't forget to give this container the dropzone-previews class 
so the previews are formatted correctly.
 -->
<div id="previews" class="dropzone-previews"></div>


<button id="clickable">Click me to select files</button>

<script>
  new Dropzone(document.body, { // Make the whole body a dropzone
    url: "/upload/url", // Set the url
    previewsContainer: "#previews", // Define the container to display the previews
    clickable: "#clickable" // Define the element that should be used as click trigger to select files.
  });
</script>
```

In the end, you can have a full page dropzone, a specific dropzone and a button to send files.

Comment: If you are still showing a drop area for your `#clickable` element, might also consider these css rules to get the same effect on the drop area styling: `.dz-drag-hover .dropzone { border-style: solid; } .dz-drag-hover .dropzone .dz-message { opacity: 0.5; }`

Answer (score 0):

When you initalize the Dropzone programmatically, you can give the selector for the drop-area as first parameter:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

$(document).ready(function () {

  var myDropzone = new Dropzone(document.body, // Make the whole body a dropzone
    { 
        url: $(val).attr("action")
        // more options if needed

    }
  );
}
```

Check out the js-code from the [bootstrap example page](http://www.dropzonejs.com/bootstrap.html). There you can find some good examples for configuration and callback functions.

Comment: you shown me the same code in the url(Make the whole body a dropzone) I posted in my question ,but that its not my requirement . have you seen the JIRA website how they did dropzone ? I posted some code that I already configured can you please send me proper reply by using my code if you know

Comment: In my page I have given very less space(Like 300 x 300 square box) I want to go with that box for click and upload but when I try to drag(when mouse enter with file) my dropzone should respond

Comment: You mean that the whole body should be a dropzone, but only the 300x300 square box should look like a dropzone?

Comment: Yes exactly , when I drag some thing on a page(anywhere on the page) my  300 x 300 box should respond, do you have any idea?

Comment: This is not exactly what you want, but you can try the following thing. Attach the dropzone to the document.body and define your 300x300 box where you want to have it with css-class `.drag-highlight`. When you drag a file over the body, dropzone.js should add `.dz-drag-hover` to the body. When you add a css-rule `.dz-drag-hover .drag-highlight{background-color: red}` your 300x300 sqare should be colored red when a file is dragged over the document...

Comment: @biking-flip : what you mean by `attr("action")` here ? . what does `action` do here ? . Can you please elaborate . Thank you .

Comment: The http://www.dropzonejs.com/bootstrap.html link is dead.